# Infinispan-10.0.1.Final: No marshaller registered for Java type java.util.UUID

Tags: java, caching, infinispan, jcache

After upgrading infinispan-jcache from 9.4.16.Final --> 10.0.1.Final, I am unable to use the cache due to marshaller error.

See https://infinispan.org/blog/

I want it working with javax.cache.*,which was the case with v9.4.16.Final. No infinispan related classes are used.

In v10.0.1.Final, I can put and retrieve UUID from the cache. But fails when CacheLoaderFactory is set.

Imports

```
import javax.cache.Cache;
import javax.cache.Caching;
import javax.cache.configuration.MutableConfiguration;
import javax.cache.expiry.Duration;
import javax.cache.expiry.ModifiedExpiryPolicy;
import javax.cache.integration.CacheLoader;
import javax.cache.integration.CacheLoaderException;
```

Code:

```
final var cachingProvider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
final var cacheManager = cachingProvider.getCacheManager();
final var config = new MutableConfiguration<String,UUID>();
config.setTypes( String.class, UUID.class );
config.setStoreByValue( false );
config.setExpiryPolicyFactory( ModifiedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf( Duration.FIVE_MINUTES ) );
config.setReadThrough( true );
config.setCacheLoaderFactory( () -> new CacheLoader<>() {
    @Override
    public UUID load(String key) throws CacheLoaderException {
        return UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String,UUID> loadAll(Iterable<? extends String> keys) throws CacheLoaderException {
        return null;
    }
} );

cache = cacheManager.createCache( UUIDCacheTest.class.getName(), config );

cache.get( "Dummy" ); // Throws exception
```

The exception is:

```
Caused by: org.infinispan.persistence.spi.PersistenceException: org.infinispan.commons.marshall.MarshallingException: No marshaller registered for Java type java.util.UUID
    at org.infinispan.marshall.persistence.impl.MarshallableEntryImpl.marshall(MarshallableEntryImpl.java:211)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.persistence.impl.MarshallableEntryImpl.<init>(MarshallableEntryImpl.java:37)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.persistence.impl.MarshalledEntryFactoryImpl.create(MarshalledEntryFactoryImpl.java:64)
    at org.infinispan.jcache.embedded.JCacheLoaderAdapter.loadEntry(JCacheLoaderAdapter.java:51)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.loadFromAllStoresSync(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:830)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.lambda$loadFromAllStores$19(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:848)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.lambda$supplyOnPersistenceExAndContinue$9(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:559)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1771)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.marshall.MarshallingException: No marshaller registered for Java type java.util.UUID
    at org.infinispan.marshall.persistence.impl.PersistenceMarshallerImpl.objectToBuffer(PersistenceMarshallerImpl.java:164)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.persistence.impl.PersistenceMarshallerImpl.objectToBuffer(PersistenceMarshallerImpl.java:132)
    at org.infinispan.mars
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Infinispan 10.0.x introduced a significant refactoring of it's marshalling code, with the default marshaller no longer being based on Serialization. Please see our [marshalling user guide](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/developing/developing.html#marshalling) for an in-depth explanation of the various marshalling options that are available.

For this use-case, as UUID is a class out of your control, Serialization based marshalling is probably the easiest way to begin. It's necesary to explicitly configure the `JavaSerializationMarshaller` and white list the required classes (UUID).

To do this with a JCache CachingProvider, it's necessary to first create the following xml configuration file for the CacheManager.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infinispan xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:10.0">
    <cache-container>
        <serialization marshaller="org.infinispan.commons.marshall.JavaSerializationMarshaller">
            <white-list>
              <class>java.util.UUID</class>
            </white-list>
        </serialization>
    </cache-container>
</infinispan>
```

This xml is then used to create the CacheManager as follows:

```java
CachingProvider cachingProvider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
ClassLoader classLoader = SimpleCacheTest.class.getClassLoader();
CacheManager cacheManager = cachingProvider.getCacheManager(classLoader.getResource("example.xml").toURI(), classLoader);
```

All subsequent caches created by the CacheManager will be configured to utilise the JavaSerializationMarshaller.

Comment: Won't adding it to the whitelist help? https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/developing/developing.html#deserialization_whitelist