# Problem with Protostream and UUID in Infinispan 13.0.0.Final

Tags: protocol-buffers, quarkus, infinispan

I'm using Infinispan 13.0.0.final with the default marshaller (protobuf). When I try to use UUID fields in my datatypes

```
data class CounterState(
    @get:ProtoField(number = 1) var index: Long? = null,
    @get:ProtoField(number = 2) var uuid: UUID? = null
)
```

I get the following error at build time:

```
.../gradle-kotlin-protobuf/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/main/io/radiosphere/ProtoSchema.java:8: error: org.infinispan.protostream.annotations.ProtoSchemaBuilderException: The class java.util.UUID must be instantiable using an accessible no-argument constructor.
public abstract interface ProtoSchema extends org.infinispan.protostream.GeneratedSchema {
```

It seems like I'm not allowed to use UUID in my types unless I generate a protoschema for it, but since UUID is a class outside of my control I can't do this.

Previous [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58815818/infinispan-10-0-1-final-no-marshaller-registered-for-java-type-java-util-uuid/58818318#58818318) on the topic have gotten the suggestion to use the JavaSerializationMarshaller, but I want to solve this while still using the Protostream Marshaller. It has also been suggested that this would be fixed in version 12.0.0 [here](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN-11426).

An example of this not working can be found [here](https://github.com/radiosphere/gradle-kotlin-protobuf/tree/UUID-example). Note that this project will not build because of the annotation processing failing as mentioned above. If it would build the proof that it is working would be shown by running the main project (ie. not the tests).

The question becomes: What do I need to do to configure UUID to be usable in my protobuf marshalled classes in Infinispan 13? Both for embedded and for a program using the hotrod client?

**EDIT:**
Based on a given answer I have also tried doing the following:

```
@AutoProtoSchemaBuilder(
    includeClasses = [UUIDAdapter::class, CounterState::class],
    schemaPackageName = "tutorial")
interface ProtoSchema : GeneratedSchema {
}
```

This makes the build work, but when starting Quarkus I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.infinispan.protostream.DescriptorParserException: Duplicate type id 1005 for type org.infinispan.protostream.commons.UUID. Already used by tutorial.UUID
    at org.infinispan.protostream.descriptors.ResolutionContext.checkUniqueTypeId(ResolutionContext.java:151)
    at org.infinispan.protostream.descriptors.ResolutionContext.addGenericDescriptor(ResolutionContext.java:97)
    at org.infinispan.protostream.descriptors.FileDescriptor.collectDescriptors(FileDescriptor.java:313)
    at org.infinispan.protostream.descriptors.FileDescriptor.resolveDependencies(FileDescriptor.java:245)
    at org.infinispan.protostream.descriptors.FileDescriptor.resolveDependencies(FileDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.infinispan.protostream.descriptors.ResolutionContext.resolve(ResolutionContext.java:57)
    at org.infinispan.protostream.impl.SerializationContextImpl.registerProtoFiles(SerializationContextImpl.java:127)
    at org.infinispan.protostream.types.java.CommonTypesSchema.registerSchema(CommonTypesSchema.java:49)
    at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.RemoteCacheManager.registerSerializationContextInitializer(RemoteCacheManager.java:422)
    at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.RemoteCacheManager.registerDefaultSchemas(RemoteCacheManager.java:437)
    at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.RemoteCacheManager.initializeProtoStreamMarshaller(RemoteCacheManager.java:409)
    at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.RemoteCacheManager.actualStart(RemoteCacheManager.java:365)
    at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.RemoteCacheManager.start(RemoteCacheManager.java:334)
    at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.RemoteCacheManager.<init>(RemoteCacheManager.java:192)
    at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.RemoteCacheManager.<init>(RemoteCacheManager.java:149)
    at io.quarkus.infinispan.client.runtime.InfinispanClientProducer.initialize(InfinispanClientProducer.java:68)
```

If I instead change to use `dependsOn` like this:

```
@AutoProtoSchemaBuilder(
    includeClasses = [CounterState::class],
    dependsOn = [org.infinispan.protostream.types.java.CommonTypes::class, org.infinispan.protostream.types.java.CommonContainerTypes::class],
    schemaPackageName = "tutorial")
```

I'm back to the build failing with:

```
error: org.infinispan.protostream.annotations.ProtoSchemaBuilderException: The class java.util.UUID must be instantiable using an accessible no-argument constructor.
public abstract interface ProtoSchema extends org.infinispan.protostream.GeneratedSchema {
```

It seems to be like Quarkus and the Annotation processor are getting in each others way here when it comes to having a simple working solution for UUID marshalling.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the `org.infinispan.protostream.types.java.util.UUIDAdapter` class in your annotation:

```java
@AutoProtoSchemaBuilder(includeClasses = [CounterState::class, UUIDAdapter::class] , schemaPackageName = "tutorial")
```

For more info, check the [documentation page](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/encoding/encoding.html#protostream-types_marshalling).

Comment: I updated my post based on this extra information. It seems that when running infinispan from Quarkus the UUIDAdapter causes a startup failure because the UUID type also gets registered from the Quarkus bootstrapping code.

Comment: Is the protostream annotation processor dependency mandatory ? In my latests demos I don't add it as a java dependency. I will try from my side the UUID adapter again too.

Comment: Have you got a link to a working demo where also Quarkus is being used? The annotation processor is necessary to generate the marshallers, if it's not there no Protostream class would be generated. If you happen to use Maven I think the processor is added for you automatically though, with Gradle and Kotlin I found you need to be more verbose

Comment: Yes, I'm using maven. The experience is not ideal if you need to add the annotation processor. I will work on the demo and check the issue at least from maven (if any)

Comment: @JohanCarlsson I confirm I can reproduce the issue, there is a sort of regression. We will try to fix that soon so gets into the Quarkus+Infinispan release. Meanwhile, the workaround I can propose is to add the Adapter in your own code.

Comment: @JohanCarlsson here is the commit in java maven project https://github.com/infinispan-demos/harry-potter-quarkus/commit/58d8ba3a10e10c665cb653545f60e00a59b1ee6c